# Different print style on CTRL+P and on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

I have a webpage which is completely style and I had implemented the CTRL+P print using `Print.css` stylesheet with media="print". No I have another requirement of a print button on the page but this print button should print the page with a different print stylesheet say print2.css.

My website is a travel booking site. So when this implemented I will be having two print options.

1. Ctrl+P print which uses print.css. Visitors can save a copy of the package details this will be a very detailed one which might extent to 3-4 pages.
2. A print button which uses print2.css. This would be short and crisp one, which will be 1 page only.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to load a new stylesheet to accomplish this. You could just add a modifier `class` on the `body`, when the user presses the button, and do the extra styling of `print2.css` using this class in your selectors. Then, show the print dialogue, and remove the class.